# How to solve computed property was assigned to but it has no setter in vue api composition?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-composition-api

I get the drawer value from my state using vue api composition:

```
import { useState, useStore } from '@u3u/vue-hooks';

setup() { 
   const { drawer } = useState('app', ['drawer']);

   return { drawer };
}
```

and in my component I pass the variable to the vuetify component:

```
<v-navigation-drawer dark app v-model="drawer" width="200" color="primary" clipped>
```

And I get the error:

```
Computed property was assigned to but it has no setter
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem? the state doesn't have setter and the v-model impact the setter of the object. so I don't see how it can resolve but to duplicate all the objects who works with v-model and come from the state.. seems to me a bad idea.

So how can I solve this error?

Comment: Use a separate setter function. :value="drawer" @input="setDrawerValue($event)"

Comment: but I can't change the drawer who come from the useState. so for every property I need to set proxy-property to update? cause I want to update my state also

Comment: setDrawerValue is supposed to call respective Vuex action/mutation. What you're using is not Vue composition API a wrapper around Vuex. You may notice `reactive` from real composition API  allows to do what you're asking about.